# How to fetch Serial Device using user defined Port Name

Tags: java, linux, tty, uart, rxtx

I am using Serial Interface which is connected to the System using USB-to-UART interface, I am using Rxtx Driver to use Serial Interface. When I connect the Serial Interface in my Linux machine, `/dev/ttyUSB*` lists the connected Serial Interface as `ttyUSB0`. I know the PID and VID of the Serial device, I need to fetch the Serial using my own name like `XXXSerial`.

When I change the `rules.d/10-XXXserial.rules` as:

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial", DRIVERS=="cp210x", ATTR{idVendor}=="7777",
SYMLINK+="XXXSerial".
```

after this change, when I connect my serial interface, `/dev/ttyUSB*` lists the Serial interface as `ttyUSB0` and `XXXSerial` (both are listed). And also `CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()` returns `false` and `CommmPortIdentifier.getName()` does not fetch the `XXXSerial` name.

How to fetch the Serial Interface using own name by changing the files in rules.d?